# how can I test my published restful web service in azure

Tags: eclipse, rest, azure, tomcat

I created a restful web service with java in eclipse
I used Eclipse toolkit to deploy my WS.

I'm just wondering how to test http requests? I mean there is the default URL to the app porvided by azure ***myapp.azurewebsites.com***
but how to do a POST or GET?
and also DO I need to chose the same tomcat version when deploying my app in azure?

I have tomcat 6 on my computer,  but in azure i chose tomcat 8 for example

thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don understand your question. You can  perform a GET request in any browser and a Post using tools like Postman or Fiddler (just to name a few). We can' tell you which path you have to use because it depends on your application but it should be the same as if you run it local (except the different host address). Also whether you have to choose the same tomecat version depends on your application and the component it uses - you are the only person who can answer that.

Comment: I'm getting error 404 ( the requested resource is not available)  when using the default URL to the published app. that's why i'm asking about tomcat version

Comment: 404 typically don't indicate a server errror but a invalid route (path not found). So you probably want to add some path to your API but I cant tell you which....

Comment: I copied the war file in the webapp folder of tomcat. and set the environment variables:




//CATALINA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0
//JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
//JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre

Comment: I mean the path of your rest services. e. g. https://myapp.azurewebsites.com/api/user/4711
My APIs dont use a default URLs so getting a 404 when invoking the default URL seems fine for me...